# Jasper report: supressed first page footer leaves blank space

Tags: jasper-reports

I need different page footers for first and other pages.
I placed one footer in `page footer` band and other in `column footer` band

I set `Print When Expression` for `page footer` band as `$V{PAGE_NUMBER} > 1`

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1383480/work/QIP%20Shot%20-%20Screen%20454.png

Jasper starts to print page footer from second page, but it leaves blank space on first page (both in preview and docx export).
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1383480/work/QIP%20Shot%20-%20Screen%20455.png

I tried to set `remove line when blank` on all text elements, it doesn't help

My jasper reports is 5.6, target format is docx

How do I remove blank space on first page?

Comment: Try setting Print When Expression on your TextElements. and set RemoveLineWhenBlank to true

Comment: Hi! I tried to set `remove line when blank` on all text elements, it doesn't help

Comment: Please do not add print when expression on page footer. You should add it to the element placed in the page footer. like on text field, static text etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is one approach using fake group footers
https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/4074-0

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.origin.{suffix}.{arbitrary_name}` property for excluding page footer for exporter.

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.origin.{suffix}.{arbitrary_name}

Maybe it will be helpful:

> It is stated on 108 of the Jaspersoft Ultimate Guide PDF that the page
>   footer always retains the declared fixed height.
>
> Add it as a standard field perhaps into another band and then print
>    only on page one using a PrintWhenExpression (see pg 119 of the
>    ultimate guide). Include an expression that effective means it only
>    prints on page one, something like:
>
> $V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1
>
> **If you need it on the bottom there are options to align the element to
>    the bottom of the band IIRC.**

From: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/822453/page-footer-space-removal-dynamically

Comment: tried, it excludes, but leaves blank space in my case